# Azure IP throttle with web.config while using Cloudflare

Tags: asp.net, azure, web-config, ip, cloudflare

I want to deny users access to my site if they have made X requests in Y milliseconds. According to Microsoft I can use [dynamic ip security](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/confirming-dynamic-ip-address-restrictions-in-windows-azure-web-sites/) in the web config.

This is how my config, that I use for testing the ip throttle, looks:

```
<security>
    <dynamicIpSecurity>
        <denyByRequestRate enabled="true" maxRequests="2" requestIntervalInMilliseconds="10000"></denyByRequestRate>
    </dynamicIpSecurity>
</security>
```

Now to my problem: Since I'm using Cloudflare I won't see the real IP of my visitors. According to Cloudflare, they provide the real IP in a couple of [headers](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170986-How-does-CloudFlare-handle-HTTP-Request-headers-). Although, it does not seem that Azure looks at these headers when checking if the IP should be denied.

My question is: Is there some way I can still use the web config way of denying requests by IP or do I need to use a code solution instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that I found the answer to my own question. I'll post my findings here for people that might have the same problem.

According to [this](https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/dynamicipsecurity) there is an attribute called "**enableProxyMode**" which

> Enables IIS not only to block requests from a client IP that is seen
>   by IIS, but also to block requests from IP addresses that are received
>   in the x-forwarded-for HTTP header.

Since Cloudflare puts the real IP of the visitor in the **X-Forwarded-For** HTTP header it works perfectly.